# Predicting lottery numbers

Tags: puzzle, lotteries

I am working on a model and formula for predicting lotto numbers. Some success. Looking at recent ozlotto and sat lotto draws (pics). There were a total of 19 numbers drawn (2x sat (6 numbers)) and 1x lotto (7 numbers) a total of 19 numbers ..... of those 19 numbers I predicted 14 out of 19 (70%) with an accuracy of +/- 3......   does anyone know of any mathematical model or formula that can predict lottery numbers

Comment: pics https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1720691014913885&id=100009190105045&pnref=story

Comment: It's interesting how you think this is "successful" when, in fact, you are no "closer" to winning with 22 than with 35 if the correct number is 23.

Comment: the question was "does anyone know of any mathematical model or formula that can predict lottery numbers"

Comment: Even if you are claiming that there is a pattern in the lotto numbers, this doesn't qualify as a math question. Maybe consider a data science forum.

Answer (score 4):

By definition of unbiased independent random numbers, there is no memory or pattern, and thus prediction is not possible.

Comment: Fabrice, I suggest you look at pics on fb page link regarding prediction.

Answer (score 2):

[lottery:] "A strange game. The only winning move is not to play"

The only reasonable mathematical model of lottery outcomes is that "Every combination of numbers has the very same probability to be the winning one, no matter what the previous outcomes".

Comment: like i said    70% numbers predicted with an accuracy of + /-  3 for each number     i provided pics of draws 22/10 .....17/11....  10/12 ....  13/12   i won a few too  its why i have not got pics of them.....   i am after 100% number prediction with an accuracy of + / -  2

Comment: @meandi: what does "accuracy of $\pm2$" mean?

Comment: ok    the 4th number (lowest to highest) this tues ozlotto should be 25 or 27 or 31     i want to be accurate within 2 of the actual number

Comment: @meandi: but that means nothing! The numbers 25 and 27 are "close" (only assuming the natural topology, though, if you know what that means), but by no means the corresponding balls in the urn are "close" in any meaningful sense. You should think of lottery numbers not as actual numbers, but only as symbols (of no intrinsic numerical meaning) that allow to distinguish a ball from another. What kind of mathematical model would you ever think of if the balls were "numbered" with symbols as $\ast$, $\uparrow$, $\sharp$, $\&$, $\%$, ... instead of numbers?

Comment: but lottery numbers are numbers so you should consider them as numbers and then you can predict them  https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1723923934590593&set=a.1714832912166362.1073741826.100009190105045&type=3&theater    that draw was a lot better.....

Comment: @meandi: but again, $39$ is as close to $40$ as any other "number". Indeed $39$ and $40$ are just numbers representing two different balls tossed in the urn which should be by no means considered "close". In any event you never showed that your purpoted "predictions" are actually so, so I don't see how you may hope to be taken seriously, given also your lack of basic understanding.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009190105045    top post on jan 10th prior to draw ....   predicted ONLY 4 numbers...  predicted 2 -that was drawn... predicted 17-  that was drawn....   predicted 43 - that was drawn.....   predicted 23 but as a comment stated "it could be 22 23 or 24"   well  22 was drawn...   that is 4 out of 4 ...

Comment: next question to ask is ....  is it a coincidence?   based on further evidence provided https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1723923934590593&set=ecnf.100009190105045&type=3&theater  25/12/16  top row....   predicted 5- 4 was drawn .... predicted 8 5 was drawn.... predicted 10 9 was drawn...  predicted 24  24 was drawn...   predicted 34 34 was drawn...  predicted 40   39 was drawn....   so the evidence shows you can indeed predict lottery numbers as draw on 10/1/16 proves ...  out of 4 numbers and only 4 numbers predicted, all were drawn with 100% accuracy

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to use past data to build a model that fits that data, even get very good 'prediction' rates within that data (when you hold some back and use the rest to predict the left over). The trouble is you only get a very good model for THAT set of data. I've noticed patterns/distribution/bias that I can model well; I could even write a set of rules for an expert system that fit  my data set almost exactly, but it only does that batch of historic data. It does not go forward (at least not yet!). It's a bit like the weather in that there are patches of 'this' (eg rain) and patches of that (eg sun) and within limits I can spot those and because it has behaved in a certain way in the past I make a prediction, of sorts, and check. But the patches of 'this' and 'that' could start to change next week and the rules Ihave no longer apply.